# N2CMS formatting a date property with <n2:Display> tag

Tags: n2, n2cms

I have an EditableDate property and am displaying it in a WebForms page with <`n2:Display>` tag. The default output is something like *7/02/2011 12:00:00 AM* however I would like to format the date like *7 February 2011*. Have tried `<n2:Display Format="{0:d MMM yyyy}">` however this just outputs *{0:d MMM yyyy}*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this: could it be that you only need the formatting part?

```
<n2:Display Format="d MMM yyyy">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ContentItem, add a new property like "XDateString" as follow :

```
...
[EditableDate("Date", 50, ContainerName = Tabs.Content)]
public virtual DateTime? EventDate
{
      get { return (DateTime?)GetDetail("EventDate"); }
      set { SetDetail("EventDate", value); }
}

public virtual string EventDateString
{
     get
     {
         if (!EventDate.HasValue) return string.Empty;

         //Format here your Date
         return (EventDate.Value.ToString("d") + " " +
                 EventDate.Value.ToString("MMMM") + " " +
                 EventDate.Value.ToString("yyyy") 
                );
     }
}
...
```

Then in design page, add :

```
<n2:Display runat="server" PropertyName="EventDateString"/>
```